# How to give a role in on_message discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

That's the code that can help to understand, it is async branch, but part of it is copied from rewrite branch, not sure it can help
How to give a role if the message consists `"test"`?

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import re

TOKEN = ""

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "{")

@bot.event
async def on_message(ctx):
 user = ctx.author
 if "test" in ctx.content:
                                      #part from rewrite branch (copied from Internet)
    member = ctx.author
    role = discord.utils.get(member.roles, name="Test")
    await user.add_roles(member, role)
 await bot.process_commands(ctx) #to let commands work
    

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

> discord.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10011): Unknown Role

Where is the mistake? And if there is a better way to do what this code does, what is it? P.S Role Test does exist, so mistake is not there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please consider reading [this](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_message) once.

on_message does not accept `ctx` as its parameter, rather it accepts a `message` parameter, here is how you can use it -

```
@bot.event()
async def on_message(message):
    if "test" in message.content:
        role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name="test")
        await message.author.add_roles(role)
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

**NOTE-** Make sure that you have a role in the server named `test`.

If there are any errors, please let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the member object you can do:

```
await member.add_roles("test")
```